# Blur function is calling when window is minimize

Tags: jquery, blur

I have text box in page on which I have written blur function in jQuery.
I don't want it to be called when the user minimizes the window and that time focus is in that box.

Comment: I don't think that can be done. What do you need this for?

Comment: i am creating a login page in which their are different input text fields. if user move from text box to other field then i am verifying the data of text box on blur event and show error message

Comment: if the user minimizes the browser with invalid input in the field, it probably should show an error message.  The input isn't valid.  If no input is an invalid condition, change the handler so that the blur handler doesn't check this, but the submit handler does.

Comment: but when window is getting focus again same text box is getting focus and error message is also there

Answer (score 1):

The only way I can think to do this is probably more work than simply making it so that it does the right thing regardless of how the focus is lost.  Essentially you'd have to rewrite it so that it did the action, not when focus is lost, but when another element on the page gains focus *after* the original element had focus.  Since the minimize button isn't part of the page, it wouldn't trigger the event until it was expanded and another element gained focus.  I can think of many things that would go wrong and the code would likely be very complicated just to handle this one requirement.

Comment: how it was handles in twitter login page? any idea

Comment: @subash - what do you mean? I don't get any validation in the ajax-based form until I do a submit.  The same is true for the non-ajax form. There doesn't seem to be any validation on blur.

Comment: if u check on twitter sign up page, if u move out from text box and if field value is invalud then it show error message

Answer (score 0):

Standard practice is that when you move away from a form field, be it clicking on another element, minimizing the window or moving to another window, that the field receives a blur event. You should take that into account always as thats what users expect.

If you really only care about when the user moves away from a field to another field, you could attach you validation routine to the focus event of the next element.

For example: if you're validating their username in a login/signup form, you could call the validate function when the password field receives focus.

This is probably not best practices, but it should work the way you're wanting.

Comment: but if user uses mouse and moved to some other field(not the immediate next then my logic will not work) is there any way to find out that any of current form control is in focus or not?

Comment: Yeah, you could do a $("input").focus(function(e){ // do something }) That should fire for *any* input that gets focus, then you can use a switch to do something based on which element got focus.

Comment: Re: your conversation about the twitter signup page. They actually fire validation on .change(). So that actually works regardless of what has focus.

Comment: $("input").focus(function(e){ // do something })  is for specific control...i want to know is their any way that to find any of current page control is in focus or not... in my form their is first and last name field which cant eb blank hence chnage event will not work if i want to throw blank error

Comment: I'm not sure *exactly* what you're trying to do, but if you want to fire an event on every element on the page that gets focus, you'd do $("*").focus(function(e){ // do something }); Thats probably the most efficient way, rather than some sort of polling for element focus function.